# NHibernate Timeout due to running out of database connections

Tags: nhibernate

I am running NHibernate 2.1 with FluentNHibernate and I am constantly getting timeouts due to connection pool filling up.   I cannot figure out why.  I am using SQL Server 2008 behind the NHibernate layer.   When I bump up the max pool count,  the connections max out again.

`Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."`

I would like to see within an ISession object to find the connections sleeping but I cannot.  Is this an NHibernate bug?   Is there a workaround?

Comment: Can we see some code of where you're using your Session, are you using the session in a using block? Are you doing session per request and not cleaning the session up afterward?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you aren't disposing the ISession when finished with it.

Comment: The problem shows up before the ISession is disposed (and it is disposed via a using() block).

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer.   It was in the configuration of NHibernate.  When we removed the following clause, the problem went away.  When we restored the clause the problem came back.

```
        <property name="connection.release_mode">on_close</property>
```